# Raytracing not working after opening my Unity Project on a different machine (Unity Engine)

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, rendering, raytracing

I am currently trying to implement raytracing into my Unity Project. When I originally worked on it, on a different system, everything worked as expected (the machine had a GTX1080ti). Now I tried opening the project on a different machine (using a RTX2080 to get better performance) but for some reason its not working anymore, even though I didn't change any settings. The raytracing does seem to have some kind of effect but just not the one I am looking for.

I am getting this weird vibration you can see in the Gif below, when activating path tracing for example. The sliders in the volume change nothing when I try moving them.

[image: An image showing vibration resulted by path tracing]

I have also gone through and made sure all the settings are activated as I want them to (TAA on scene Camera, Quality Level with raytracing set to default, all sorts of settings enabled on the HDRP settings asset, volume with raytracing enabled, raytracing enabled on materials ...)

When I try implementing raytracing into a different project on this machine everything works as expected as well. My guess would be that something got lost in the transfer (I used Github) but I just cant figure out what. Does anyone know what I have to add to make it work?

And if that is not the problem what else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. For some reason the settings in my Quality > HDRP > `Your Render Setting` did not get transferred. It was the gitignore blocking it. For anyone running into the same problem I'd suggest checking the HDRP Wizard in the rendering tab at the top of the screen. It tells you if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code. Try using Debug.Log, see if the raycasts are firing in script.

EXAMPLE:

`RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up); Debug.Log("hit = " + hit);`

Good luck finding the culprit :)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I am not using a raycast I am using raytracing to render my project. But I found my solution. Thanks for trying to help anyway! :)

Comment: Ah I must have misread it. Good to hear you found the solution.